# Point Existing domain in godaddy.com to new ec2 instance without domain migration

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Hi I know this question is asked a few times, but I have a different problem.

I had a website & domain www.exampledomain.com hosted on godaddy. I have shifted my website on amazon ec2 and I want to use my domain that is on godaddy.com.

I have pointed the A records of my domain to my Elastic IP of my instance on EC2. And so this website is started running with http://www.exampledomain.com (IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx).

I still have code on godaddy server and I am keeping web hosting on godaddy for my other websites.

When I use the old website (at godaddy) IP yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy on browser, it redirect the website to new Amazon Instance, instead of showing the website on godaddy. Why is that? I have added a "@" at the end of title on my website on Amazon, just to get rid of confusion as both the old and new website are alike.

What else should I do to make godaddy IP to keep pointing to the website hosted there and the domains to point to Amazon EC2 (well the domain pointing is already done) ? Did I miss any setting? Do I need to change the nameservers? I am not aware of nameservers but I have heard that its required to change.

There is a server in Amazon called Route53, i guess it is used to migrate domain from godaddy to amazon. So if I use it? Will it completely migrate my domain to Amazon (I don't want to do that) and next time I have to pay Amazon for the domain fee and not to godaddy?

Please note that I want to keep my domain (website name) on godaddy and website  hosting on Amazon.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe. Your website redirects me to https://xyz.xyz/ which appears to load normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have redirection rules that point to www.exampledomain.com. When that happens, browser makes new dns query and loads website from amazon, where A record is pointed. To avoid it, try looking at redirection rules in .htaccess on godaddy account and comment them. If they are not needed for webiste to work, that should help.

If you can't resolve redirection problem on godaddy, you can edit your hosts file and add line:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx www.exampledomain.com
```

That will let you to open domain on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: Thanks it is working. I had no idea that previous website was being redirected using htaccess file. I have changed the real website and IP to dummy to keep myself safe.